# Difference in image superimposition achieved with MATLAB function imfuse and that using ImageJ composite image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, imagej

I have two time-lapse images of a membrane surface. Both images were supposed to show the same region. But while adjusting focus, captured field might have drifted a bit.  I used two routes to visualize the amount of drift - MATLAB v 2021a and ImageJ. With MATLAB, first I tried superimposing two images using `imshowpair`. Original grayscale images are [fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3Ct2.png)
and [mov](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziJKj.png). `imshowpair(mov,fix)` yields [imshowpair_comp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWKfR.png). It clearly shows possible drift. Then I tried using `imfuse` function as follows:

```
RF = imref2d(size(fix));
RM = imref2d(size(mov));
RM.XWorldLimits = RF.XWorldLimits;
RM.YWorldLimits = RF.YWorldLimits;
comp = imfuse(fix,RF,mov,RM,'falsecolor','Scaling','joint','ColorChannels',[1 2 0]);
```

It gave the composite image [imfuse_comp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czqYF.png). Next, I carried out image registration and I got [imregcorr_comp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYJlD.png).

```
tForm = imregcorr(mov,fix,"similarity");
movTransform = imwarp(mov,tForm,"OutputView",RF);
imshowpair(movTransform,fix)
```

This image shows properly aligned composite image. I tried doing the same using ImageJ.

> 1. Open fix.tiff in ImageJ. Image->Colors->Channels Tool->Composite->Red.
> 2. Open mov.tiff in ImageJ. Image->Colors->Channels Tool->Composite->Green.
> 3. Image->Colors->Merge Channels

This gave the composite image [imagej_comp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6sQQ.jpg). This composite image obtained from ImageJ clearly shows that there was no misalignment in the two images to begin with!
I am unable to figure out where I went wrong. Now I am really confused between two routes - and which route to believe in. Can someone please help me out?
Thanks!